# How do I send errors by throwing an exception in a json asmx client/server call?

Tags: json, exception, soap, asmx

I have an asmx web service that can be called using either SOAP or JSON. When I throw custom exceptions in a method (for instance for telling user he/she sent an invalid password) they are properly sent to client if it's a SOAP call. But if it is a JSON call it seems like it will always be a standard 500 Internal Server Error - no matter what exception I am throwing.

How do I send proper error messages if user calls service using JSON?

Comment: I just realized the following: When web.config is set to customErrors=On then the correct exceptions are sent to client if it's a SOAP call but if it's a JSON call then always 500 Internal Server Error. If I change to customErrors=Off then it's the opposite.

Comment: So question now is: What do I do so that i works no matter if client connects using JSON or SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was solved by adding the following to my web config

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
<webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"></jsonSerialization>
</webServices>
</scripting>
```

My custom exceptions are now returned as expected regardless of consumer.

Rgds
AJ